# Which is longer lasting HSS-E or HSS coated wth TiN?

Tags: machining, tools

I'm just gonna purchase taps and dies for my most commonly used metric screws. I want them to last for as long as they can (not that they will be used so often, I just want them like that). I also will be hand cranking them, so actual high speed cutting won't be done. So which is better for my application, HSS-E or HSS coated in TiN??

Comment: Off-topic for Engineering.  I'll move this to a site where it may be on-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not related to automotive maintenance or repair.

Comment: Am I the only automotive repair enthusiast who believes that my tap and die set is an essential tool in the arsenal?

Comment: I make tools of my own sometimes. I'm getting by with just embedding/soldering bolts onto something, but I figure this might come in handy.

Comment: This question is totally on-topic. Ask me how I know :)

Answer (score 3):

HSS-E steels are HSS steels alloyed with Cobalt.

Cobalt makes steels harder and increase the heat resistance. Detriments are the increased breaking susceptibility and reduced toughness. [Source in German](https://gewindeaufschneider.de/blog/hss-oder-hsse/#more-991)

Since heat resistance is of no concern in your application I would choose TiN coated HSS taps.

Comment: Kinda contradictory that HSS-E should be able to cut faster, yet the you say it is more prone to breaking and has reduced toughness.

Comment: That's unless my ebay order gets clandestinely swapped while in transit.

Comment: @Dehbop - I'm failing to see where he says HSS-E is able to cut faster?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Just generic stuff that I read online, not in the German page he provided.

Comment: @Dehbop on machining operations an important wear factor is heat, heat tolerant tools allow faster cutting speeds thereby decrease machining costs. In case of hand cranked taps the heat resistance is of no concern, more important is resistance against operator errors

Comment: By knowing that it cuts faster, that means it's not the type that would be brittle.

Comment: @Dehbop please look at this [diagramm](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/af/Verschlei%C3%9Fkomponenten.png/800px-Verschlei%C3%9Fkomponenten.png) (again in german). It will show you that thermal wear (Diffusion and Verzunderung) are the most important wear (Verschleiß) factors on high cutting speeds (Schnittgeschwindigkeit)